# Using AJAX, and retrieving the ready states

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the code behind for the retrieving the ready states and it's works good for me. May I please ask how can I add a else statemen in this content. Like if the url is not available I would like to print a message to user. Like

```
document.getElementById("div p").innerHTML = "Ping is not success!";
```

and try to make it looks like little bit more fancier then a plain html text. 
Her is the my code:

```
url = "<whatever you want to ping>"
ping = new XMLHttpRequest();    
ping.onreadystatechange = function(){

    document.body.innerHTML += "</br>" + ping.readyState;

    if(ping.readyState == 4){
        if(ping.status == 200){
            result = ping.getAllResponseHeaders();
            document.body.innerHTML += "</br>" + result + "</br>";
        }
    }

}
ping.open("GET", url, true);    
ping.send();
```

Comment: `if(ping.status == 200){
            result = ping.getAllResponseHeaders();
            console.log(result)
        }else {
        document.getElementById("div p").innerHTML = "Ping is not success!"; 
    }`

Comment: It fails i do get an error that's says bad url.  https://jsfiddle.net/9Lnq4a7f/1/

Comment: @Itslearning Correct; scripts running on `https://fiddle.jshell.net` cannot read responses from `https://google.com` because they have different origins. Scripts running on `https://fiddle.jshell.net` can only read other resources from `https://fiddle.jshell.net`, or from servers that serve CORS headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a requests ends, the `readyState` is `4`, but the `status` may be a value other than `200`. If the `status` is `0`, that indicates a network error or CORS failure (for cross-origin servers). If it is some other value (like `404`), that means the script reached the server, but the server didn't handle the request successfully (either because the URL path used wasn't meaningful, or a server-side error occurred, etc.)

```
ping.onreadystatechange = function(){

    document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" + ping.readyState;

    if(ping.readyState == 4){
        if(ping.status == 200){
            result = ping.getAllResponseHeaders();
            document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" + result + "<br>";
        } else if(ping.status == 0) {
            document.getElementById("foobar").innerHTML = "Ping is not successful! Could not get any response from the server, due to a network failure, CORS error, or offline server."; 
        } else {
            result = ping.getAllResponseHeaders();
            document.getElementById("foobar").innerHTML = "We got a response from the server, but it was status code " + ping.status;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i don't think i have understood exactly  what you meant. But I have made a jsfiddle . Do you have a little time to look at because i think i am not writing correct.  https://jsfiddle.net/xefd1xo7/3/

Comment: @Itslearning Several issues: your fiddle doesn't actually call `open` or `send`, and it refers to ID values that don't exists. Here is a cleaned up version that works: https://jsfiddle.net/xefd1xo7/5/. Also, `8.8.8.8` is not a sever name in this context; it will load the path `/8.8.8.8` on the current origin (e.g., `https://fiddle.jshell.net/8.8.8.8`). Furthermore, you should understand the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which disallows `domainA.com` from reading messages from `domainB.com`, so a request to `http://8.8.8.8/` from JSFiddle would fail.